# Codecadamy Parse API Lesson 1 | Broken? | Creating your first object

Tags: javascript, api

This lesson should be ridiculously easy. They spell out answer, but myself and 10+ people in the forums can't get this lesson to work.

Are we implementing the code incorrectly? Is the lesson misleading? Is the answer checker just broken?

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-B8H1e/0#!/exercises/0

```
$(window).on("html_loaded", function(e) {
    $(".submit_button").click(function(e) {

        // 1. Set the type of Parse Object, in this case use 'Post'
        var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");

        // 2. Create a new object of type Post
        var myPost = new Post() ;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, seems to be broken as there is no user feedback after you click submit.

Part 2 shows the same answer as what you already have:

```
$(window).on("html_loaded", function(e) {
    $(".submit_button").click(function(e) {

        // This creates our new Post object
        var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
        var myPost = new Post();

        ...

    });
});
```